# $\frac{d}{dt} (\det (\phi(t))) = \text{tr}(A(t)) \det(\phi(t))$

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, determinant, tensors

**Problem.** 
Let $A(t)$ be a real-valued, continuous $n \times n$ matrix function defined for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$ and let $\phi(t)$ be a real-valued, continuously differentiable $n \times n$ matrix function such that $\phi'(t) = A(t) \phi(t)$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Here, $\phi'(t)$ is the matrix function obtained from $\phi(t)$ by taking the derivatives of each of its entries. Show that $\frac{d}{dt} (\det (\phi(t))) = \text{tr}(A(t)) \det(\phi(t))$.

**My Question.** 
My idea was to set up an induction somehow, so I've written out the 2 x 2 and 3 x 3 cases, hoping to spot some pattern, but that has been fruitless.

For context, this is coming from a prior qualifying exam at my school. My school recommends Hoffman and Kunze and Friedberg Insel Spence, and I've read those books cover to cover. I'm bringing that up because, as far as I can tell, this is some tensor algebra stuff, so I'm sure there's some "easy" theorem for those with advanced training. But I have to pass the qual before I have access to that advanced training! So I'm looking for hints or a solution at the level of a first year graduate linear algebra course, like I might employ on my upcoming qual. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For a proof see for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_formula

Comment: Can you prove that $d(\det)(A)(B) = \det A  \,\text{tr}(A^{-1}B)$?